# Input controls wont disable in FireFox, but do in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.6.2 and calling a function to disable some html text input controls, based on a date. The code works as expected in Google Chrome, but not in Firefox. I was using .attr, but switched it to .prop. It still works in Chrome, but not Firefox.

Here is my jQuery code.

```
  // Get the dates to compare
        var lock_date = new Date($("#lock_date").val()).getDate();
        var now = new Date().getDate();
        // Check if the lock_date is today
        if (lock_date == now) {
            $("#indications-row input").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#allocations-row input").prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $("#indications-row input").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#allocations-row input").prop("disabled", true);
        }
```

I've read some other posts, that say if you change .attr to .prop it will work, but it still doesn't. If anybody knows a work around, please post and answer.

Comment: It works for me Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/THKQd/)**

Comment: As an aside, your code could be greatly simplified:  `$("#indications-row input").prop("disabled", lock_date == now);`, etc.  Remove your entire if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (lock_date == now) {
        $("#indications-row input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#allocations-row input").attr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#indications-row input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#allocations-row input").attr("disabled");
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong, and jQuery's docs say explicitly to **not** do this: "Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead." http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/